# How to fasten join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

two mysql tables like A and B

```
emp_A(id,name,some_text)     PK is: id

emp_B(sr_no,emp_id,loc,adrr) PK is: emp_id+sr_no

emp_sr(sr_no,a,b)            PK is: sr_no
```

My tables are like this. Im going to query like

```
select A.name, B.loc 
from emp_A, emp_B B 
where A.id=B.em_id 
and sr_no =123
```

emp_A table has around 3L records
emp_B table has around 8L records.

How can I fasten my join query??

Please help me??????

Comment: Are you asking how to make the query faster? If so please provide the results of `EXPLAIN` with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `WHERE`, use the `ON` clause of your join.

```
select A.name, B.loc from emp_A
    inner join emp_B B on A.id=B.em_id and sr_no =123
```

When you use only a `WHERE` clause, first every record in A is joined to every record in B, then some are filtered out.  So you were building a massive table as an intermediate step.

When you use an `ON` clause, the records that don't match are filtered out while the join is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select A.name, B.loc from emp_A A join emp_B B on(A.id=B.emp_id) join emp_sr C on (B.sr_no=C.sr_no) where C.sr_no = 123
```